# I am trying to set up a virtual environment on Windows 10 so I can run Python and Django. What do I need to do?

Tags: python, django, environment

I am reading a book on Python.  It said to set up a directory "learning log" and then on the command line enter "learning_log$ python -m venv ll_env" which I did, and got an error "learning_log$ is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file".  What do I need to do that I have not done?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It is a normal convention to use `xxxxx$ command to run` to show you the command to input in shell, while `xxxxx$` is simply representing the _Prompt_  of the shell, which is not part of your input

Comment: I will recommend to watch some tutorial on python basics to make things clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple. the `learning_log$` is not the part of the command but is is just the path showing that you are in that directory.

If you open your command prompt, you will find something like this;

```
C:\Users\username>
```

Which just shows the path.

There are many ways to create virtual environment in python. As you seem to be a beginner, you should start with `virtualenv`.

first install it;

```
pip install virtualenv
```

then go to your project directory and run the command;

```
virtualenv venv
```

This will create a virtual environment named as `venv`

To activate it run the command;

```
venv\scripts\activate
```

Now if you install any package, that will be stored in this virtual environment and not globally.

Another way to create a virtual env is by using `pipenv`

```
pip install pipenv
```

Then in your project directory;

```
pipenv shell
```

This will create a virtual environment there and will be activated also when created.

Next time if you want to activate it, just run the same command again `pipenv shell`.

This creates a pip file which will store your dependencies.

Those dependencies can be downloaded at once by using the command;

```
pipenv install
```